# In a Jenkins multibranch plugin cancel previous pull request builds when a new commit is pushed

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline, ghprb

Having used Jenkins freestyle project and [Github pull request builder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/)
I am able to Cancel Build on Update using below configuration under `Build Triggers`.

[image]

However, I want to do the same in Multi-branch pipeline? Any pointers on how to do so?